# Realizer method for straight line graph drawing of planar graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to find out the straight line grid drawing of a planar graph by Realizer Method. Schnyder labeling  and realizer of the graph has already been computed as follows:

[image: planar graph]

Now, I have to find out the straight line grid co-ordinats for the vertices in the above graph.

The algorithm I am following is as follows:

[image: image of text of algorithm]

[image: image of more text of algorithm]

[image]
The resultant straight line grid output is as follows:

[image: output]

I am finding it hard to understand how the value of **n1(v)** and **n2(v)** in the algorithm  has been calculated. For example: in the above result, for vertex x, n1(x)=1, n2(x)=1.

My question is, is there any easy way to calculate this n1(v) and n2(v)?

Detailed description of the realizer method can be found [here](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=QAo8DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=realizer+method++Nishizeki&source=bl&ots=dR9vCi-qfZ&sig=aF5zxwNJnkYzaRNR4pKxQ5Iz9NE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=realizer%20method%20%20Nishizeki&f=false)

Comment: The rest of section 4.3.4 shows how to calculate n1 and n2 for all the vertices.

Comment: I haven't found any detailed calculation in rest of the section 4.3.4. Can you please provide me the resource you are talking about? @AakashM